# Rename files in directory based on names of files on another directory

Tags: linux, bash, files, rename

I'm not sure if this has been asked here but here is my problem. I have files in lets say `dir1` named:

```
File 1.mp4
File 2.mp4
etc..
```

Now on directory `dir2`, I have files named:

```
Sub 1.srt
Sub 2.srt
etc..
```

How would I be able to rename `Sub 1.srt` so it becomes `File 1.srt`.  So basically renaming all `*.srt` files to have the name of `*.mp4` files. There is the same amount of files on both directories and using `printf %s\\n *` files are sorted.

Comment: How can you know that `Sub 1.srt` should be named `File 1.srt` and not `File 2.srt`? Is there an index, alphabetical order or something like this to use as a criteria?

Comment: @Kira there is the same amount of files on both directories and using `printf %s\n *` files are sorted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since both directories contain the same number of files, here's an approach that saves file names in two arrays and then does the rename for each index in the list of array indices (as both arrays have the same length) :

```
mp4paths=(dir1/*.mp4)              # save mp4 file names in array
mp4names=("${mp4paths[@]##*/}")    # remove leading path components
name=("${mp4names[@]%.*}")         # remove extension
srt=(dir2/*.srt)                   # save srt file names in array
for i in "${!srt[@]}"              # for each index in the list of array indices 
do                                 # do stuff here...
mv "${srt[$i]}" dir2/"${name[$i]}".srt
done
```

This should work with all kind of file names.
For a "dry-run" replace `mv` with `printf '%s -> %s\n'`.

Answer (score 1):

```
paste -d=  <(ls dir2/*.srt)  <(ls dir1/*.mp4) | 
  perl -nlE 's/=dir1(.*).mp4/" "dir2$1.srt/; say("mv \"",$_, "\"")'  |
  bash
```

- First line produces lines like `dir2/sub 1.srt=dir1/file 1.mp4`
- second line changes them to `mv "dir2/sub 1.srt" "dir2/file 1.srt"`
- third line executes thos lines

Comment: @don_crissti: sorry I temporary delete the answer, because I cut and paste a wrong version and the previous was dangereous...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the files probably *aren't* literally named 'File 1.mp4' and 'Sub 1.srt' (although the script still works if they are) but that the numbers in both sets of files match:

```sh
#! /bin/sh

dir1='./dir1'
dir2='./dir2'

find "$dir1" -maxdepth 1 -name '*.mp4' | while IFS= read f ; do
    num=$(echo "$f" | sed -e 's/^.* \([0-9]\+\)\.mp4/\1/')
    subtitle=$(find "$dir2" -maxdepth 1 -name "* $num.srt" | head -1)
    if [ -n "$subtitle" ] ; then
        bn=$(basename "$f" .mp4)
        mv "$subtitle" "$dir2/$bn.srt"
    fi
done
```

Note: this will work an all files except those with newlines in the filename.  The `head -1` is to prevent the script from failing if there happens to be more than one .srt file with the same number....in that situation, the first file found will be renamed, the other(s) ignored.

If you want the subtitles moved into the same directory as the .mp4 files, change the `mv` line to:

```
mv "$subtitle" "$dir1/$bn.srt"
```